# Relational Algebra Tag

Tags: support, documentation

I recently added a Relational Algebra section to the SQL documentation.
@CL had deleted it with the explanation of

> A full overview/explanation of relational algebra does not belong in
>   the SQL tag; there already is a "relational-algebra" tag. At most, an
>   explanation of how relational algebra relates to SQL would be on
>   topic.

I can't find this tag to enter the documentation into.  Could someone point me in the right direction please?

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/revisions/7311

[image]

Comment: If you don't find that tag at http://stackoverflow.com/documentation, there's a Propose a New Tag button right there.

Comment: I've undeleted it (though there's no guarantee that it will stay that way if people disagree) Deleting good content because it would hypothetically be a better fit in a tag that it is not possible to create documentation for doesn't seem a good idea to me.

Comment: At the moment, this topic is completely off topic because it does not even try to show how it relates to SQL.

Comment: Fair point @CL - I'll have to spend some time this weekend correcting that.  For now I'll add a picture to my question which I found in 'Database Systems' by Michael Kifer, Arthur Bernstein & Philip M Lewis which shows the role Relational Algebra plays in translating an SQL query.

Comment: From what I can tell, that subject is not related to SQL in any way.
Sure, it uses sql statements to explain what's going on, but that's where the similarity ends. Imo, the topic has no place in the SQL tag. Only 2 of the examples actually have the relational algebra syntax in there.

Comment: @MartinSmith: On the other hand, we shouldn't just "keep" good off-topic content because it's well-written.

Comment: @Cerbrus - Relational algebra is the theoretical foundation that SQL is based on. How is that off topic?

Comment: It's a topic of it's own, @MartinSmith.

Comment: @Cerbrus - If I bought a book about SQL and it has a chapter on relational algebra I wouldn't regard it as off topic.

Comment: You say _if_... ___Do___ those books have a chapter on relational algebra, or is that just speculation?

Comment: @Cerbrus - yes. Chapter 3 of this book for example http://tsql.solidq.com/books/insidetsql2008/ - https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiJQ0.png

Comment: The Open University course I did on Relational Database Systems (M876) had a section dedicated to Relational Algebra and a smaller section on Relational Calculus.  We even got software called RAS which allowed us to use the Relational Algebra System.  The Constraints that we had to list for our ER Diagrams was in Relational Algebra (e.g. **constraint** (**project** Property **over** EntNo) **difference** (**project** Shares **over** EntNo) **is empty**).  The diagrams made no sense without them.

Answer (score 2):

It seems [relational-algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relational-algebra) isn't big enough to have [a Documentation section of its own](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/relational-algebra).

Comment: That's what I thought, so I added it to SQL as it seems a perfect complement to SQL but it got deleted.